# What is the area of $\triangle$ $MNO$?

Tags: geometry

Parallelogram $ABCD$ has area of 1.

Centers of the $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ sides are labeled M, N.

The $\overline{CM}$ and $\overline{DN}$ lines intersect at $O$ while their intersections with the $\overline{AB}$ line are marked
$Q$, $P$.

What is the area of $\triangle$ $MNO$?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to see that $MDCN$ is parallelogram and knowing that diagonals divide parallelogram into four triangles of equal area, the answer is $\large{\frac{1}{8}}$

Comment: Thank you. It's easy to spot right now, just wasn't intuitive for me. Don't know why. :)